# UWP community fade animation not changing the opacity at all

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, windows-composition-api

```
await VolumeRing.Fade(value: 1f, duration: 20, delay: 0).StartAsync();
```

My problem is very simple. I am using UWP community toolkit to animate the fade animation of a xaml element but I've even checked with breakpoints; the above code does bring its opacity from 0 to 1, instead opacity remains at 0 (which is the default I've set for the element).

### Update

```
public CompactNowPlayingPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(VolumeRing).Opacity = 0;           

}
private async void VolumeFadeIn()
{
    await VolumeRing.Fade(value: 1f, duration: 20, delay: 0).StartAsync();
}
private async void VolumeFadeOut()
{
    await VolumeRing.Fade(value: 0f, duration: 1500, delay: 3000).StartAsync();
}

//invoked by KeyboardShortCuts
private void ChangeVolume(bool increase)
{
    if (IsControlPressed)
    {
        VolumeFadeIn();
        if (increase&&Media.Volume<100)
            Media.Volume += 5;
        else if(!increase&&Media.Volume>0)
            Media.Volume -= 5;
        VolumeRing.Value = Media.Volume;
        VolumeFadeOut();
    }
}
```

**XAML**

```
 <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <vlc:MediaElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
                          Name="Media"                     
                          HardwareAcceleration="True"
                          AutoPlay="True">
        </vlc:MediaElement>
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,32,0,0">
            <notification:SfProgressBar Name="VolumeRing"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                        Margin="0,16,48,0"
                                        FontSize="24"
                                        Width="Auto"
                                        Value="{x:Bind Media.Volume, Mode=OneWay}"
                                        Height="Auto"
                                        FillColor="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColor}"
                                        BackRimStrokeThickness="12"
                                        StrokeThickness="12"
                                        ProgressType="SolidCircular"
                                        >
                <notification:SfProgressBar.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="WhiteSmoke" Opacity="0.7"/>
                </notification:SfProgressBar.Foreground>
            </notification:SfProgressBar>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like by default the Toolkit is using the `Visual.Opacity` for the `Fade` animation, and if you are setting the `Opacity` to `0` in your xaml code, it's not going to work as the `Visual.Opacity` is not in sync with `UIElement.Opacity`.

So you can either **remove** the `Opacity="0"` xaml code and then set the `Opacity` of your `VolumeRing`'s `Visual` to `0` in your constructor, like this -

```
ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(VolumeRing).Opacity = 0;
```

Or, **keep** the `Opacity="0"` xaml code but set `AnimationSet.UseComposition` to `false` before calling the `Fade` method -

```
AnimationSet.UseComposition = false;
```

### Update

OK, just had a look at the source code and I was wrong, the Toolkit is **not** using Composition API by default. Kind of surprising but anyway... You should remove the `Visual.Opacity` setting in your constructor and put back the `Opacity` setting in your xaml code.

By the way you are calling them, I guess you want to wait for the element to show first and then hide it. So you will need to change the hide and show methods from `async void` to `async Task`.

Comment: your 1st option works fine but only for the first time, as soon as I fadeout the VolumeRing and again its opacity is faded out to 0, so next time I try again to fade in, then it wont work

Comment: @touseef option 2? I'd also like to see how exactly you fade in and out...

Comment: option 2 doesn't work at all. and see the update for more details :)

Comment: Please see the update version of question now. I accidently updated your answer before, so dont approve that :P

Comment: No worries. Just to confirm, you removed the `Opacity` setting in xaml right?

Comment: Yes I have not set any Opacity property on VolumeRing in the xaml

Comment: I have updated the question now to add the xaml code as well

Comment: ok and then I should await these 2 methods while calling right? when I do that , then I would need to make method ChangeVolume "async" as well right? so changeVolume would be fine with "async void"?

Comment: It depends on if you want your animation to finish before conituning to the next one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146573/discussion-between-justin-xl-and-touseef).